# Esri Map in Angular page click no longer loading to lat long? 'toJSON' of null at Object.b.locationToAddress

Tags: angular, typescript, esri

Currently getting an error when you click on the esri map. This function used to work. It is occuring at the locatorTask.locationToAddress(event.mapPoint).then(function (response) {

The error looks like this in the console:
[image]

Here this code:

```
  mapView.when(function () {
  mapView.popup.autoOpenEnabled = false;
  mapView.on("click", function (event) {
    searchWidget.clear();
    mapView.popup.clear();
    locatorTask
      .locationToAddress(event.mapPoint)
      .then(function (response) {
        // If an address is successfully found, show it in the popup's content
        mapView.popup.content = response.address;
        var address = response.address;
        showPopup(address, event.mapPoint);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // If the promise fails and no result is found, show a generic message
        mapView.popup.content = "No address was found for this location";
        showPopup("No address found.", event.mapPoint);
      });

    mapView.popup.visible = true;
  });
})
```

Thanks for any advice or help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your JavaScript API version? The parameters were changed in version 4.12.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/4.12/index.html

"Changed locatorTask.locationToAddress() arguments from (location, distance, requestOptions) to now accept (params, requestOptions). The params object has two properties: location and locationType."

The new documentation can be found here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-Locator.html#locationToAddress

Your code should be:

```
locatorTask
      .locationToAddress(location:{event.mapPoint})
      .then(function (response) {
```